# Como fazer com que uma coluna se fixe quando chegar às extremidades?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Em um layout de duas colunas, se a primeira for maior do que a segunda (altura), vai ficar um espaço em branco no lugar da segunda quando rolarmos a página até certo ponto. Quero que quando chegar no final da coluna ela fixe ao invés de continuar rolando junto com a página. E ao rolar de volta ela deve rolar junto com a página. Como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: A solução que eu queria era o que TobyMosque postou. Mas obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carlos, primeira coisa a ser fazer é delimitar uma área para as suas colunas, você pode usar um elemento que faça um wrapper para a coluna da esquerda e para a da direita,

então adicione um listener para o evento "scroll" para este container, desta forma você vai conseguir ancorar a coluna da direita no topo ou no rodapé deste container.

segue uma sugestão de implementação:

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
var content = document.querySelector(".content");
var esquerda = document.querySelector(".esquerda");
var alturas = document.querySelectorAll(".altura");

var margin = {};
var style = window.getComputedStyle(esquerda, null);
margin.Top = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("margin-top").replace("px", ""));
margin.Bottom = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("margin-bottom").replace("px", ""));
margin.Total = margin.Top + margin.Bottom;
var prevTop = container.scrollTop;

container.addEventListener("scroll", function (event) { 
  if (esquerda.offsetHeight > container.offsetHeight) {
    if (prevTop < container.scrollTop) {
      var pos = container.scrollTop + container.offsetHeight;
      var esq = esquerda.offsetHeight + esquerda.offsetTop;
      if (pos > esq) {     
        esquerda.style.top = (pos - esquerda.offsetHeight - margin.Total) + "px";
      }
    } else if (container.scrollTop < esquerda.offsetTop) {     
      esquerda.style.top = container.scrollTop + "px";
    }
  } else {
    esquerda.style.top = container.scrollTop + "px";
  }
  prevTop = container.scrollTop;
});

[].forEach.call(alturas, function (altura, indice) {
  altura.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
    event.target.parentNode.parentNode.style.height = altura.value + "px"; 
    var event = new Event("scroll");
    container.dispatchEvent(event);
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.header {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  top: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  top: 40px;
  bottom: 80px;  
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  z-index: 2;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.esquerda {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 1800px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.direita {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  height: 2800px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 320px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

#altura {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="esquerda">
    <label>
      Altura desta div 
      <input class="altura" type="number" value="1800" step="100" min="100" max="5000" />
      px
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="direita">
    <label>
      Altura desta div 
      <input class="altura" type="number" value="2800" step="100" min="100" max="5000" />
      px
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">

</div>
```